# Cual es lo novedoso en ConstraintLayout o algunas diferencias básicas con los demás layouts?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

desde que actualicé Android Studio, cada nueva actividad creada, por defecto trae android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout, me gustaría pedirles que me orienten un poco al respecto.

Comment: [Orientese un poco al respecto](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)...

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, puede te cierren la pregunta ya que se basa en opiniones o demasiado amplia para enumerar todas las diferencias, te dejo una respuesta con algunos tutos que puedes mirarte y comprender donde están las diferencias.

Comment: Alfredo, te sugiero revisar preguntas y respuestas que se han realizado anteriormente en el sitio @Alfredo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `ConstraintLayout` es el nuevo elemento para diseñar los layouts.
La diferencia que trae es la simplicidad en combinar elementos mas o menos como el `ReleativeLayout` pero pudiendo anclar los elementos entre si con sus 4 ejes.

```
A-------B
|       |
C-------D
```

Se puede especificar un ratio para cada vista con la propiedad `layout_constraintDimensionRatio`

```
<ImageView
...
`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"`
...
/>
```

Usar guias `bias` para posocionar elementos que parten de aquel punto relativamente.

### Tutoriales sobre diseñar ConstrainLaout

- [Building interfaces with ConstraintLayout](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7)
- [Exploring the new Android ConstraintLayout](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1)
- [Guide to ConstraintLayout](https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013)
- [Constraints layout the best layout ever!](https://android.jlelse.eu/constraints-layout-best-layout-ever-230175272c0f)