# Error para mostrar una Activity, elementos amontonados posición 0,0

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, activity

Buen día, estoy empezando a trabajar con la herramienta **AndroidStudio** (O sea soy un total principiante) y tengo un pequeño "error" (La verdad no se que sea). Mi diseño es así:

[image: Diseño de la Activity]

Pero al emular la aplicacion, se muestra de esta manera:
[image: Activity emulada]

Los elementos estan unos sobre otros... Tambien pongo el codigo **xml** del mismo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingRight="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="14dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="andresk21.com.proyecto.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTitulo"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titulo"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPaquete"
        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
        android:paddingRight="14dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/numero_paquete"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuscar"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/boton_buscar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:onClick="llamarSegundoActiviy"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="121dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Insisto en que soy nuevo en esta herramienta (por si la solucion es simple para la mayoria de ustedes)... De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Como consejo, nunca uses posiciones absolutas en android, en ios si es una practica habitual porque los tamaños son siempre los mismos, pero en sistemas android las resoluciones y tamaños que encontraras tienen un numero de combinaciones descomunales como para intentar que cuadre algo sin usar posiciones relativas.

Comment: @ManuelRobles en este caso esta usando ConstraintLayout y son requeridas :(, de hecho el uso incorrecto de ConstraintLayout  es en realidad el problema por lo cual se amontonan las vistas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no es un problema es que tienes el soporte [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html), y estas usando como layout principal un [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html), te sugiero revises esta información en el sitio:

[Cual es lo novedoso en ConstraintLayout o algunas diferencias básicas con los demás layouts?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69220/cual-es-lo-novedoso-en-constraintlayout-o-algunas-diferencias-b%C3%A1sicas-con-los-de)

[Elementos amontonados Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57616/elementos-amontonados-android-studio/57785#57785)

[Android Studio mensaje: Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82971/android-studio-mensaje-missing-constraints-in-constraintlayout)

**Como solución, si no deseas usar `ConstraintLayout`, simplemente cambia en tu layout .xml el tipo de layout**, por ejemplo de :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

a otro tipo de layout por ejemplo `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
```

o `RelativeLayout`:

```
   <RelativeLayout
```

Si deseas usar [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html), entonces debes definir restricciones en tus vistas para que aparezcan en posición correcta cuando se ejecute tu aplicación, ya que en diseño se pueden mostrar correctamente pero cuando inicias tu aplicación se muestran todas las vistas en la misma posición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, solo comento tambien que al usar `LinearLayout` los elementos se posicionaban uno encima de otro... Usando `RelativeLayout` todo bien, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Andres, en el caso de usar LinearLayout en este caso, debes usar android:orientation=vertical (el default es horizontal), con eso se mostrarían correctamente. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Podrías realizar algunos cambios en tu layout para solucionar el problema y además simplificar el código:

En vez de utilizar `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX`, usar `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf` y `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` para configurar la posición de cada elemento en el eje `x` de manera relativa a otros elementos en vez de utilizar valores fijos.

En vez de utilizar `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY`, usar `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` y `android:layout_marginTop` para configurar la posición de cada elemento en el eje `y` de manera relativa a otros elementos en vez de utilizar valores fijos.

Se pueden eliminar los elementos relacionados con `padding` y `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` ya que no afectan significativamente la forma en que se mostrará el layout

El layout podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="andresk21.com.proyecto.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTitulo"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titulo"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPaquete"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/numero_paquete"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblTitulo"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuscar"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/boton_buscar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="llamarSegundoActiviy"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPaquete"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```