# Enganchar objetos en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Veran, en Android Studio cuando creo un nuevo objeto, este no esta anclado a la pantalla del movil y debo hacerlo manualmente en los 4 costados para asegurarme que este en una posición fija.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen muestro 2 objetos TextView. Uno anclado a la pantalla, que aparece nada más crear el proyecto. El otro no lo esta.

Y esto es lo que pasa al ejecutarlo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay un modo para hacer que al crear un objeto este ya anclado, o al menos que permite conectarlo a la pantalla rapidamente?

Edito: Un modo para anclar un objeto más rapidamente es pulsando en los 4 botones de anclaje que se muestran en los atributos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Extrañamente, aunque lo pruebo y funciona perfectamente, parece que las conexiones son algo inestables, pudiendo ser cada conexión de distinto tipo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado: Cuando conecto los objetos, en vez de hacerlo al layout, es probable que quieran engacharse a otros, lo cual dara dificultades para posicionar los objetos pues pueden tambien cambiar su posición. Aparte de que si enganchas un objeto a otro, al intentar mover uno, el otro tambien se mueve.

Answer (score -1):

En este caso ambos elementos deben tener restricciones, de otra forma aunque en la vista de diseño los veas en posición correcta, cualquier elemento que no tenga restricciones definidas se mostrará en la posición 0,0:

[Error para mostrar una Activity, elementos amontonados posición 0,0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101591/error-para-mostrar-una-activity-elementos-amontonados-posici%C3%B3n-0-0)

Tienes que definir la restricción si estas usando `ConstraintLayout`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La opción de cambiar el tipo de Layout no me ha servido (cada tipo de Layout es más arisco que el anterior), pero el atajo que muestras en la imagen que adjuntas fue bien, aunque noto algo raro. Lo explicare editando mi pregunta.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez ok Miguel agrega más información. Definitivamente si usas ConstraintLayout, todos los elementos deben tener sus restricciones para posicionarse dentro del Layout, hasta el día de hoy Android Studio no muestra el estado real cuando la aplicación esta en funcionamiento, por lo que puedes ver los elementos correctamente posicionados y en realidad no es así.

Comment: Lo que quiero es precisamente es colocar facilmente objetos en el room, de igual forma que podria en otros programas como Visual Studio, en el que ponia en un sitio un objeto y ahi se quedaba. Lo que quiero saber es como darle a cada objeto restricciones para que se quede en su sitio en el Layout.

Comment: ahhh la opcion hasta el dia de hoy si deseas ver lo que agregas evita el ConstraintLayout

Comment: ¿Me puedes explicar mejor que quieres decir, por favor? Sugieres no usar ConstraintLayout. ¿Que hago entonces?

Comment: Recomendable para los -1 es recomendable agregar la razón, esto para mejorar las respuestas, en caso de algún error..