# Por qué se reacomodan los controles al mover algún elemento?

Tags: android, android-studio

En mi vista de diseño los controles los tengo de la manera que aparecen en la imagen, pero cuando ejecuto mi aplicación se muestra todo bien ordenado, y cada vez que intento mover algún elemento siempre regresa a la posición que se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código correspondiente es:

```
class IncomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var ingresosDao: IngresosDao
    var spinner: Spinner? = null
    var button: Button? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income, container, false)
        ingresosDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(requireContext()).ingresosDao()
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar) as Button
        spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spMes) as Spinner
        val adapter: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(requireContext(),R.array.Meses, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
        spinner!!.adapter = adapter
        button!!.setOnClickListener{
            val Mes = spMes.selectedItem.toString()
            val Monto = txtMonto.text.toString().toFloat()
            val TipoIngreso = txtTipoIngreso.text.toString()

            if (TipoIngreso.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Complete El Campo Anterior", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else{
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.putExtra("id", 0)
                intent.putExtra("mes", Mes)
                intent.putExtra("monto", Monto)
                intent.putExtra("tipoIngreso", TipoIngreso)
                activity!!.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
                txtMonto.setText("")
                txtTipoIngreso.setText("")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        return  view
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Creo que es necesario que incluyas en tu pregunta la definición del activity donde están esos controles para que puedan ayudarte a revisar por qué se acomodan de esa forma

Comment: @Alfabravo este es el código asociado a los controles que se muestran en la imagen

Comment: Si es un error de diseño el codigo a mostrar es el de tu xml no el del archivo .kt

Comment: Si usas un `ConstraintLayout`, la posición de cada elemento se define en función de la posición de los demás. Ejemplo: Debajo de este otro y a esta distancia. Así que obviamente, cuando mueves uno, se mueven todos los que tengan la posición relacionada. Te recomiendo que aprendas sobre el uso de ese tipo de Layout.

Comment: por que la vista por default es un constraintLayout la vista se acomodan en base a restrincciones. Tienes un panel para cambiar las restricciones o por el archivo xml en codigo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que seguramente estas usando ConstraintLayout y en este caso las vistas contenidas dentro de este tipo de layout deben tener restricciones ("Constraints"),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si estas no se definen, el resultado es que cuando cargues tu aplicaciòn las vistas dentro del layout se veran amontonados, similar a lo que sucediò en esta pregunta:

**[Error para mostrar una Activity, elementos amontonados posición 0,0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/101591/95)**

Es importante revises la documentaciòn:

[Como crear una Interfaz de Usuario responsiva usando ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html?hl=es)

> Para definir la posición de una vista en ConstraintLayout, debes
> agregar al menos una restricción horizontal y una vertical. Cada
> restricción representa una conexión o alineación con otra vista, el
> diseño de nivel superior o una guía invisible. Cada restricción define
> la posición de la vista a lo largo del eje vertical u horizontal, por
> lo que cada vista debe tener un mínimo de una restricción para cada
> eje, aunque a menudo se necesitan más.
>
> Cuando sueltas una vista en el editor de diseño, esta permanece donde
> la dejas, incluso si no tiene restricciones. Sin embargo, esto solo
> sirve para facilitar la edición. Si una vista no tiene restricciones
> cuando ejecutas su diseño en un dispositivo, se abre en la posición
> [0,0] (la esquina superior izquierda).
>
> En la figura 1, el diseño se ve bien en el editor, pero no hay
> restricción vertical en la vista C. Cuando este diseño se abre en un
> dispositivo, la vista C se alinea horizontalmente con los bordes
> izquierdo y derecho de la vista A, pero aparece en la parte superior
> de la pantalla porque no tiene restricción vertical.

Figura 1.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Figura 2.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]