# Android studio las imagenes se sobreponen

Tags: android-studio

estoy empezando a aprender android estudio en mis tiempos libres y tengo un problema que no encuentro la forma de solucionar.

Estoy poniendo varias imágenes pero se ponen unas encima de otras envede una debajo de otra, creo que es algo de las coordenadas que se ponen todas en 0,0. Creo que puede faltar algún atributo en mi código xml

Si alguien puede ayudarme, lo agradezco.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/foto1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="36dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/foto2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="86dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/foto3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/foto4"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="186dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Revisa: [Activity, elementos amontonados posición 0,0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101591/error-para-mostrar-una-activity-elementos-amontonados-posici%c3%b3n-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

En vez de:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Prefiero usar:

```
<RelativeLayout
```

Añadiendo:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Y para evitar choques puedes añadir:

```
android:layout_Below="@id/tuPrimerImagen"
```

El `layout_below` puedes aplicarlo a cada `ImageView` que tengas, declarando el `id` del elemento que está encima de este. Por ejemplo, si tienes un `TextView` tres `ImageView` lo aplicas así:

```
//ImageView1
android:id="@id/idImageView1"
android:layout_below="@id/idTextViewTitulo" //esto lo posiciona debajo del TextView
//ImageView2
android:id="@id/idImageView2"
android:layout_below="@id/idImageView1"
//ImageView3
android:id="@id/idImageView3"
android:layout_below="@id/idImageView2"
```